# Is it possible to replicate this website's AJAX call? (web-scraping question)

Tags: python, ajax, api, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape the table from this website.

It seemed like a simple scrape, being able to parse the HTML directly, although I came across the following problem.
On each page, the first 3 rows are different to what's shown on the webpage, and the last 3 rows aren't scraped.

I done a bit of digging, and realised the website is grabbing the data from this source (which means all of the 'data I'm trying to scrape isn't available directly through the website source-code)->
 https://www.saasmag.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=companydatatable_action&year=2018

When previewing the XHR requests (on chrome), its clearly visible what the website is requesting - although when I visit the same link, I'm just presented with this: `{"draw":null,"recordsTotal":0,"recordsFiltered":0,"data":[]}`

I think it is protected or maybe needs some sort of auth.

Would there be a way around this sort of issue?

Comment: Try to copy the XHR as CURL from chrome and then see what parameters it uses. Most likely you're missing a buch of cookies.

Comment: Yeah, this was exactly it.  I didn't even know about this until 30 minutes ago. Cheers man! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick, I just needed to use a session handler.

```
import requests

url = r"https://www.saasmag.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=companydatatable_action&year=2018"

session = requests.Session()
session.get("https://www.saasmag.com/saas-1000-2018")

formdata = {'draw': ['2'],
 'columns[0][data]': ['0'],
 'columns[0][name]': '',
 'columns[0][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[0][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[0][search][value]': '',
 'columns[0][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[1][data]': ['1'],
 'columns[1][name]': '',
 'columns[1][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[1][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[1][search][value]': '',
 'columns[1][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[2][data]': ['2'],
 'columns[2][name]': '',
 'columns[2][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[2][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[2][search][value]': '',
 'columns[2][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[3][data]': ['3'],
 'columns[3][name]': '',
 'columns[3][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[3][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[3][search][value]': '',
 'columns[3][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[4][data]': ['4'],
 'columns[4][name]': '',
 'columns[4][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[4][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[4][search][value]': '',
 'columns[4][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[5][data]': ['5'],
 'columns[5][name]': '',
 'columns[5][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[5][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[5][search][value]': '',
 'columns[5][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[6][data]': ['6'],
 'columns[6][name]': '',
 'columns[6][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[6][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[6][search][value]': '',
 'columns[6][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[7][data]': ['7'],
 'columns[7][name]': '',
 'columns[7][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[7][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[7][search][value]': '',
 'columns[7][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[8][data]': ['8'],
 'columns[8][name]': '',
 'columns[8][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[8][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[8][search][value]': '',
 'columns[8][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[9][data]': ['9'],
 'columns[9][name]': '',
 'columns[9][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[9][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[9][search][value]': '',
 'columns[9][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[10][data]': ['10'],
 'columns[10][name]': '',
 'columns[10][searchable]': ['true'],
 'columns[10][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[10][search][value]': '',
 'columns[10][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'columns[11][data]': ['11'],
 'columns[11][name]': '',
 'columns[11][searchable]': ['false'],
 'columns[11][orderable]': ['false'],
 'columns[11][search][value]': '',
 'columns[11][search][regex]': ['false'],
 'order[0][column]': ['11'],
 'order[0][dir]': ['asc'],
 'start': ['0'],
 'length': ['2500'],
 'search[value]': '',
 'search[regex]': ['false']}

while url:
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
    }
    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=formdata)
    for company in r.json()['data']:
        print(company)
    url = None
```